# How to append dict in to the csv file and excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary

I have dict in python and i want to append it into the CSV file and Excel file.

I have one function that return the below dict

```
d = {'Engine': u'2.0 TSI MLB', 'Category': 'Category', 'Installation': 'Installation', 'Features': 'Features', 'Title': 'Title', 'Recommended Software': 'Recommended Software', 'UniCONNECT+': 'UniCONNECT+', 'Make': u'AUDI', 'Price': 'Price', 'Stock Power': 'Stock Power', 'Desctiption': 'Description', 'Related Hardware': 'Related Hardware', 'Year': u'2018', 'Hardware Included': 'Hardware Included', 'Model': u'A4', 'Product Type': 'Product Type', 'LB-FT': 'LB-FT', 'HP': 'HP', 'Octane': 'Octane', 'Media1': 'Media1'}
```

and i have called the function from the loop and function returns same dict with different data and I have to write it to the CSV and Excel file in the loop 
file should look like below

`Engine       |  Category    |   Installation |........
 2.0 TSI MLB  |  car         |   5            |........
 2.0 TSTI MLB |  bike        |   6            |........
 8.0 BL       |  car         |   8            |........
 2.0 TSI MLB  |  car         |   6            |........`

Comment: What kind of help are you asking for? Please share you code, show us what you have tried so far and ask valid question for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import pandas
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter

sample_dict = {'Engine': u'2.0 TSI MLB', 'Category': 'Category', 'Installation': 'Installation', 'Features': 'Features', 'Title': 'Title', 'Recommended Software': 'Recommended Software', 'UniCONNECT+': 'UniCONNECT+', 'Make': u'AUDI', 'Price': 'Price', 'Stock Power': 'Stock Power', 'Desctiption': 'Description', 'Related Hardware': 'Related Hardware', 'Year': u'2018', 'Hardware Included': 'Hardware Included', 'Model': u'A4', 'Product Type': 'Product Type', 'LB-FT': 'LB-FT', 'HP': 'HP', 'Octane': 'Octane', 'Media1': 'Media1'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_next_dict = iter([sample_dict]*5)
    headers = sample_dict.keys()

    # create csv file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.isfile('test.csv'):
        with open('test.csv', 'w')as csv_file:
            csv_file.writelines(', '.join(headers))

    # create excel file if it does not exist
    if not os.path.isfile('test.xlsx'):
        book = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
        sheet = book.add_worksheet("TestSheet")
        for (idx, header) in enumerate(headers):
            sheet.write(0, idx, header)
        book.close()

    # open the files and start the loop
    with open('test.csv', 'a+') as csv_file:
        book = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
        sheet = book.get_sheet_by_name('TestSheet')

        # loop through all dictionaries
        for d in get_next_dict:
            values = [d[key] for key in headers]
            csv_string = '\n'+', '.join(values)
            # write to csv file
            csv_file.write(csv_string)
            # write to excel file
            sheet.append(values)
        book.save(filename='test.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you write a new csv/excel? Or do you append to an existing csv/excel?

In principle you can do what you want with `pandas`. From your first dict create a `pandas.DataFrame`. Append all the dictionaries you get inside the loop. In the end write the data frame to a csv or excel:

```
# ... bevore the loop
d = function_that_returns_a_dict()
df = pandas.DataFrame(d, index=[0])
# or alternatively read the exising csv/excel and the append all dictionaries
# df = pandas.read_csv(...)
# df = pandas.read_excel(...)

#... inside the loop
d = function_that_returns_a_dict()
df = df.append(d, ignore_index=True)

# ... after the loop
df.write_csv('name.csv')
df.write_excel('name.xlsx')
```

Comment: I want to write like this open the file existing if not there create it and then put headers and then append dict to the file not after the loop completes all in the loop